# Save a playlist to file in a relatively safe fashion

Tags: java, file, serialization

I am writing a [music player](http://hypnosplayer.org) in Java / JavaFX.

The player allows the user to create playlists (which are a list of songs).

These user-created playlists are displayed in the music player's library. I would like to build reasonable precautions that the data is not lost due to the program crashing, the system shutting down in the middle of a write, etc.

Here is my saveLibraryPlaylist() method. Do you have any suggestions on how it can be improved?

```
//Set at runtime to be an OS-specific location in the user's home directory
//such as ~/.hypnos/playlists/ or %AppData%\Local\Hypnos\playlists\, etc. 
private File playlistsDirectory; 

public void savePlaylists () {

    ArrayList <Playlist> playlists = new ArrayList <> ( library.getPlaylists() );

    ArrayList <Playlist> errors = new ArrayList <> ();

    for ( Playlist playlist : playlists ) {
        if ( playlist == null ) {
            LOGGER.info( "Found a null playlist in library.playlists, ignoring." );
            continue;
        }

        try {
            saveLibaryPlaylist ( playlist );
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            LOGGER.warning ( "Unable to save library playlist " + playlist.getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
            errors.add( playlist );
        }
    }

    if ( errors.size() > 0 ) {
        ui.warnUserPlaylistsNotSaved ( errors );
    }
}

//Assumptions: playlist != null, playlist.getName() is not null or empty, and no playlists in library have the same name. 
private void saveLibaryPlaylist ( Playlist playlist ) throws IOException {

    Path targetFile = playlistsDirectory.toPath().resolve ( playlist.getName().hashCode() + ".m3u" );
    Path backupFile = playlistsDirectory.toPath().resolve ( playlist.getName().hashCode() + ".m3u.backup" );
    Path tempFile = playlistsDirectory.toPath().resolve ( playlist.getName().hashCode() + ".m3u.temp" );

    boolean savedToTemp = false;

    try {
        playlist.saveAs( tempFile.toFile(), true );
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        savedToTemp = false;
        LOGGER.info( "Unable to write to a temp file, so I will try writing directly to the playlist file." +
            "Your data will be saved in a backup file first. If this process is interrupted, you may need to manually " +
            "recover the data from the backup file.\n" + e.getMessage() );

        if ( Files.exists( targetFile ) ) {
            try {
                Files.move( targetFile, backupFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING );
            } catch ( IOException e2 ) {
                LOGGER.info( "Unable to move existing playlist file to backup location (" + backupFile.toString() +
                    ") will continue trying to save current playlist, overwriting the existing file." + 
                    "\n" + e2.getMessage() );
            }
        }
    }

    try {

        boolean movedFromTemp = false;

        if ( savedToTemp ) {
            try {
                Files.move( tempFile, targetFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING );
                movedFromTemp = true;
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                movedFromTemp = false;
            }
        }

        if ( !movedFromTemp ) {
            playlist.saveAs( targetFile.toFile(), true );
        }

    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        LOGGER.info( "Unable to save playlist to file: " + targetFile.toString() + "." );
        throw e;

    } finally {
        Files.deleteIfExists( tempFile );

    }
}
```

And here is Playlist.saveAs():

```
public void saveAs ( File file, boolean includeName ) throws IOException {
    if ( file == null ) {
        throw new IOException ( "Null file specified." );
    }

    try ( FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter( file ) ) {
        PrintWriter playlistOut = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter( fileWriter ) );
        playlistOut.println( "#EXTM3U" );

        if ( includeName ) {
            playlistOut.printf( "#Name: %s\n", getName() );
            playlistOut.println();
        }

        for ( Track track : getTracks() ) {
            playlistOut.printf( "#EXTINF:%d,%s - %s\n", track.getLengthS(), track.getArtist(), track.getTitle() );
            playlistOut.println( track.getPath().toString() );
            playlistOut.println();
        }

        playlistOut.flush();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList <Playlist> errors = new ArrayList <> ();
```

It is customary to declare the type as List if you don't *really* need O(1) access time to random locations. For example:

```
List <Playlist> errors = new ArrayList <> ();
```

If you get in this habit, then your IDE will auto-suggest method APIs which use interface types (List) rather than implementation types (ArrayList) as you write new methods which accept e.g. `errors` as a parameter.

Similar advice if you ever create a HashMap: declare as Map instead.

```
ArrayList <Playlist> playlists = new ArrayList <> ( library.getPlaylists() );
```

I don't know what kind of Collection `.getPlaylists()` returns. But was it really necessary to make a copy of it? I don't see you doing anything crazy to it like mutating it.

The name `saveLibaryPlaylist()` seems too verbose, it might naturally have been `savePlaylist()`, or even `save()` given that the signature is very clear about accepting exactly one playlist.

```
//Assumptions: playlist != null, playlist.getName() is not null or empty, and no playlists in library have the same name.
```

Make the non-null requirement an annotation and/or a javadoc comment, please. The other two requirements, about having a name that is unique, sound like promises that the Playlist class already makes, or should make.

```
        errors.add( playlist );
```

Wow! Finally, a java `catch` clause that instead of ignoring actually "handles" an error, with deferred UI warning. Kudos, that's perfect.

I can't imagine that `playlist.getName().hashCode() + ".m3u"` would yield user-friendly directory listings. It wouldn't kill you to throw in a few characters of `.getName()` to offer a hint. Also, bear in mind that hash codes can collide. Longer ones (e.g. sha224) collide less often.

You might consider verifying that playlistsDirectory is writable, for example by `stat()`ing it. It may be unwritable due to permissions, or due to no free space.

```
    savedToTemp = false;
    LOGGER.info( "Unable to write to a temp file, so I will try writing directly to the playlist file." +
        "Your data will be saved in a backup file first. If this process is interrupted, you may need to manually " +
        "recover the data from the backup file.\n" + e.getMessage() );
```

You didn't describe the use case this is designed to deal with. Add a comment saying how one could get a system into a bad state which this tries to recover from. If the use case involves running the app under different userids, then consider encoding userid as part of the filespec to avoid such collisions. Given that `.saveAs()` failed for one file, it's not obvious to me why other attempts would magically succeed. Is this a windows thing, where another process holding a readonly file descriptor prevents your write attempts?

```
} catch ( IOException e ) {
    savedToTemp = false;
```

This is odd. Don't you want to set it false, save, set it true, and then there's a catch? Maybe you need two booleans, but it seems complex and flakey, it seems like simple control flow could eliminate at least one of them. In any event, the current code is clearly not manipulating `savedToTemp` in the way you intended, as there is literally no code path that can ever set it true, so `Files.move(tempFile, targetFile` will never execute.

I guess you intend to keep foo.m3u and foo.m3u.backup lying around in the directory, that's fine. Consider deleting foo.m3u.temp upon entry *and* upon exit, just in case of leftovers from a previous run.

It's hard to maintain code that never runs. Consider adding a non-null annotation to saveAs(), and then delete this which apparently can never trigger:

```
if ( file == null ) {
    throw new IOException ( "Null file specified." );
}
```

In the `includeName` code, this is odd:

```
        playlistOut.println();
```

It would have been more natural to printf `"#Name: %s\n\n"`, unless there's some windows CRLF thing I'm not getting, and println produces a needed CR.

I didn't see any mention of `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`, so I assume you're relying on locale, and you're fine with that randomly changing from time to time.

I assume `track.getArtist()` never outputs a "-" dash, or at least " - ". If it does, you may want to escape it to ensure the playlist is still parseable.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all of the foregoing, on at least linux, this code could still cause data to be lost in the case of an immediate power failure or pressing the reset button.

To fix that, you need to change the move line to include `ATOMIC_MOVE`:

```
Files.move( tempFile, targetFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE );
```